# Create columns from row value pairs in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, pivot-table

Is it possible to roll up multiple rows into columns with the column name as one of the returned values without multiple joins?

Example:

Table: `user`

| ID | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | steve@gmail.com | steve |
| 2 | jan@gmail.com | Jan |

Table: `meta`

| ID | user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | key_1 | value_1 |
| 101 | 2 | key_1 | value_2 |
| 102 | 1 | key_2 | value_3 |
| 103 | 2 | key_2 | value_4 |

Desired query result:

| ID | email | name | key_1 | key_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | steve@gmail.com | steve | value_1 | value_3 |
| 2 | jan@gmail.com | jan | value_2 | value_4 |

Currently, I use multiple left joins to generate this query, but as the list of keys grows, it would be great to prevent having to use more and more left joins.

```sql
SELECT u.*, meta1.meta_value AS 'key_1', meta2.meta_value AS 'key_2'
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN meta as meta1 ON meta1.user_id = u.ID
LEFT JOIN meta as meta2 ON meta2.user_id = u.ID
WHERE 1=1
AND meta1.meta_key = 'key_1'
AND meta2.meta_key = 'key_2'
```

I'd love to just be able to do something like the following which is obviously invalid in its current form

```sql
SELECT u.*, meta.meta_value as meta.meta_key
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN meta as meta ON meta.user_id = u.ID
WHERE 1=1
AND meta.meta_key IN ('key_1', 'key_2')
```

My current compromise is that if the list of keys grows large, I can just return a cell that concats the key/value pairs.

For reference, this is a WordPress database.

Comment: If a single column (instead of two separate `key1` and `key2`) is acceptable, then you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` combined with `meta.meta_key IN ('key_1', 'key_2')`.

Comment: This is PIVOT. You already use the method with multiple joins. Another method is conditional aggregation. Both methods uses definite output columns list. And the third method is dynamic SQL in stored procedure - this method does not need the output columns list to known, and it even allows to modify this columns listdepends on some conditions (for example, exclude some definite column or any column which does not contain the values which matches to some criteria, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- `CASE` statements to extract your specific key values
- `MAX` aggregation to remove your NULL values that your `CASE` statement will generate, hence grouping on the other selected column from the "*user*" table

```
SELECT u.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'key_1'
                THEN m.meta_value         END) AS key_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'key_2'
                THEN m.meta_value         END) AS key_2
FROM       user u
INNER JOIN meta m
        ON u.ID = m.user_id
GROUP BY u.ID,
         u.email,
         u.name
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nNuQ9HafYYVU1UB93QpVLk/0).